# How do I design my Node.js API so that I can also consume it from the server side?

Tags: api, node.js, mongodb, express, api-design

I have an API that returns some JSON from mongodb:

```
// In router.js
var api = require('api') 
app.get('/lists', api.lists);

// In api.js
var db = require('db')
exports.lists = function(req, res) {
  db.lists.find({}, function(err, lists) {
    res.send(lists);
  });
};
```

Is there a way to design the API so that I could also consume it from within my Node.js app? I'm trying to avoid having to duplicate any of the database code outside the API. I basically have a controller that can render the data server-side:

```
// In controller.js
var api = require('api')
exports.page = function(req, res) {
  res.send(api.lists()); // This won't work
};
```

I found a hacky solution which was to pass a callback function to the api.lists(), but I have a feeling this is the "wrong" way to achieve this:

```
// In api.js
exports.lists = function(req, res, callback) {
  db.lists.find({}, function(err, lists) {
    if(callback){
       callback(lists);
    } else {
       res.send(lists);
    }
  });
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to consume your own api? Never heard of this before. Perhaps you want to use models that you can use in two different places...look into express.

Comment: This sounds lot like wsdl/webservice discovery i.e. being able to automatically create methods/properties based on the api calls you expose. If so, good luck, there's been a few attempts to standardise this nothing has stuck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that in your current code you are coupling your API to the response object. You can decouple them with something like this:

**In router.js** instead of using api.lists as the callback, define a function that will call api.lists with a callback that is wired to the response object. In this case api.list DOES NOT need to know about the response object but the function that we are creating does.

```
// In router.js
var api = require('api');
app.get('/lists', function(req, res) {
  api.lists(function(err, lists) {
    if(err) {
      res.send('error page');
      return;
    }
    res.send(lists);
  });
});
```

**In api.js** we remove the reference to the response object. Now it will just call whatever callback it received with the appropriate data (err + lists). It's up to the callback to do whatever it pleases with the result.

```
// In api.js
var db = require('db')
exports.lists = function(callback) {
  db.lists.find({}, function(err, lists) {
    callback(err, lists);
  });
};
```